# Transformer with multi input

Tags: csv, tensorflow, neural-network, transformer-model, sequential

I would like to ask does anyone have idea how to provide two sequences within a transformer model( multi head attention to make it work like cross attention), I tried many times but doesnt understand how to perform two same kind of inputs ( type csv : numerical data, dimension for both csv 128,32 and same for other one)

```
Model = sequential()

Input1 = tf.keras.input(shape=[128,32])

Input2 = tf.keras.input(shape=[128,32])

Mha = tf.keras.layers.MultiheadAttention(num_heads=2)
Output_tensor = Mha(Input1,Input2)

Retune Model
```

This is just a dummy code that I understood from tensorflow, If someone can provide a better example, It would be very helpful, I am trying to perform cross attenion over two inputs with multi head attention

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

An example of cross attention can be found in the official API document.
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/MultiHeadAttention

```
layer = MultiHeadAttention(num_heads=2, key_dim=2)
target = tf.keras.Input(shape=[8, 16])
source = tf.keras.Input(shape=[4, 16])
output_tensor, weights = layer(target, source,
                               return_attention_scores=True)
print(output_tensor.shape) # (None, 8, 16)
print(weights.shape) # (None, 2, 8, 4)
```

In the [call method of `MultiHeadAttention`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/b80dd12da9c0bc3f569eca3455e77762cf2ee8ef/keras/layers/attention/multi_head_attention.py#L543), the first argument `target` is query, the second argument `source` is value, and when `key` is None (default value), key and value are the same.
Then, when target and source are the same, this is self-attention.